# Content scripts with 'run_at' set to 'document_end' but it modifies DOM after page is once loaded

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

In my extension, I am trying to modify the URLs of the `<img>` tags in DOM to `https://...` I have set the `run_at` attribute to `document_end`, but unlike the Chrome documentation, it modifies DOM after the page sub-resources (images) are once displayed (the images are fist displayed for a short (but annoying) time, then disappears as https is not supported for those images). I am expecting, if https is not supported for images, they should not be displayed even for a short while. The code is the following.

manifest.json:

```
...

"content_scripts": [    
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
...
```

content.js:

```
images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        if (images[i].src.indexOf("http://") === 0)
                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("http://", "https://");
```

Comment: You will have better results using the `chrome.webRequest` api to redirect all image requests.

Comment: @rsanchez I was originally using `webRequest` API to upgrade image request to https in `onBeforeRequest`, but am having problems in redirecting then back to http if https redirection fails. I need a way to redirect image requests in my `timeout_fun`. `redictUrl` does not work.

Comment: It could work for initial redirection. you need to redirect them back in your code if they fail

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you script is executed asynchronously. Chrome only guaranties that DOM is ready for `document_end` content scripts. Maybe you could inject css at `document_start` that makes all images invisible before your processing

Comment: I was thinking the same, but do not know how to make it synchronous. Actually, my aim is not hiding the images, but I want their URLs to upgrade to https and redirect them back to http if https fails. I tried `document_start` but no change.

Comment: You cannot execute you code synchronously. You script and DOM loading code may even work in different processes. My understanding that you want to prevent flickering, I guess css modifications would work good here. Or you could interrupt all image requests using way rsanchez suggested. Then start form the scratch with page DOM when you are sure no image loaded at all